# Is it possible to show Poll results as a table in Views?

Tags: views, importing-exporting, polls

I want to show the results of a Poll (core module) in Views.

However, the only way to show any Polls in Views is just as a full node (as they appear to a normal user).

I want to be able to display it as a table so that I can make it easily exportable to Excel (using the [Views Export XLS](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_export_xls) module).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below modules :

1. [Responsive Tables](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_tables)
2. [Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/data)
3. [FooTable](https://www.drupal.org/project/footable)